# call javascript while rendering a partial in rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to call some javascript while rendering a partial in rails 3.
like:

```
_my_partial.html.erb
```

Whenever this partial renders, a javascript function should be called.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `_my_partial.html.erb`:

For `html`:

```
# partial code

<script type="text/javascript">
  your_function();
</script>
```

For `haml`:

```
# partial code

:javascript
  your_function(#{@variable});
```